# How can I put a user input option in an if statement (Python/HTML)

Tags: python, html, forms

I am making a form for a website and for one part I have to add the giftwrapping to the final cost if the user selects it. 
checked = form.getvalue("giftwrap")

I tried:

```
elif total > 150 and (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC") and checked:
    print "<p>Tax: $",tax3,"</p>"
```

I also tried:

```
elif total > 150 and (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC") and
form.getvalue("giftwrap"):
    print "<p>Tax: $",tax3,"</p>"
```

None of them seem to work. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Downvoted, Question does not show any research effort and is unclear..

Comment: heres my formula for tax 3: tax3 = ((total-disc)+giftwrp)*0.12. I am not getting the correct answer so Im assuming that it doesnt work.

Comment: definitely use bc.lower = "bc" rather than checking every possible capitalisation. Also does your b1 field include newlines ? Lots more debugging to do before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Print your conditions:

```
print total > 150, b1.lower() == 'bc', checked
```

If prints True True True then it works. If at least one of conditions is False: check this condition first. If output is silent elif does not works (some of 'if' before gets True).